# Find Value in json array and append one more json array to value's parent node.(optimized)

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I have following JSON array as input

```
var trees = [
  {
    name: "alex",
    lastname: "watson",
    city: "California",
    state: "Alameda",
    childrens: [
      { name: "shane watson", city: "Troy", state: "Alabama" },
      {
        name: "adam watson",
        city: "Palmer",
        state: "Alaska",
        childrens: [
          { name: "ana watson", city: "Avondale", state: "Arizona" },
          { name: "ama watson", city: "Douglas", state: "Arizona" }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "adam",
    lastname: "ronaldo",
    city: "Bradenton",
    state: "Florida",
    childrens: [
      { name: "austin ronaldo", city: "Alhambra", state: "California" },
      {
        name: "kira ronaldo",
        city: "Calexico",
        state: "California",
        childrens: [
          { name: "sam ronaldo", city: "Chico", state: "California" },
          {
            name: "godwin ronaldo",
            city: "Eureka",
            state: "California",
            childrens: [
              { name: "michael ronaldo", city: "Buffalo", state: "New York" }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

1. Find out city in JSON array variable trees (eg. city = "Buffalo" or name = "Godwin ronaldo")
2. Add another node to that path (eg. add this node => {name:'alver ronaldo' ,city:'Athens', state: 'Ohio'}  where city = "Buffalo" or
   name="godwin ronaldo")

> Note: tree variable should be updated and when i do console.log(tree)
>   it should give me complete array with updated node

I tried to google lots of solutions but didn't worked, when its working they are getting too much bulky code & sometimes they do not update main root variable just take part in other variable and update it.

Following is fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/3kt52fpd/31/

It's working till path- I am able to get path and console value of path using eval function but not able to append a value to that path.
Thanks for the help in advance!!!!

Comment: who is doing -1 man after changing the question and providing fiddle lol :D
weird peoples at the stack

Comment: You definitely don't need `eval` for this. Finding nodes given a predicate function is an easy recursive function. If I understand you correctly that an in-place modification is fine, then you don't even need any additional immutability magic to do the updating.

Comment: and I didn't understand anything that u want to convey. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the `trees` variable above...

This function will depth-first walk a list of tree `nodes`, passing each one to the `predicate` function given, and returning the ones that match.

```
function findMatchingNodes(nodes, predicate) {
  const results = [];
  function walk(node) {
    if (predicate(node)) {
      results.push(node);
    }
    (node.childrens || []).forEach(walk);
  }
  nodes.forEach(walk);
  return results;
}
```

We can then use this to find the matching nodes:

```
const matches = findMatchingNode(
  trees,
  (n) => n.city === 'Buffalo' || n.name === 'godwin ronaldo'
);
```

And then we can use `Array.forEach` to update those in-place to add the new nodes:

```
matches.forEach(node => {
  const children = node.childrens || (node.childrens = []); // Ensures there is a childrens array
  children.push({ name: "alver ronaldo", city: "Athens", state: "Ohio" });
});
```

And so, when we `console.log` the `trees`variable, the two matching nodes have indeed new children:

```
// ... snip ...
{
  name: "godwin ronaldo",
  city: "Eureka",
  state: "California",
  childrens: [
    {
      name: "michael ronaldo",
      city: "Buffalo",
      state: "New York",
      childrens: [
        {
          name: "alver ronaldo",
          city: "Athens",
          state: "Ohio"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      name: "alver ronaldo",
      city: "Athens",
      state: "Ohio"
    }
  ]
}
```

Full JSfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/5sve3nxc/

### Edit – also accessing the node parents

If you need to access the full path from the tree root to the matching node, you can use something like

```
function findMatchingNodePaths(nodes, predicate) {
  const results = [];
  function walk(node, parents) {
    const path = parents.concat(node);
    if(predicate(node)) {
      results.push(path);
    }
    (node.childrens || []).forEach((node) => walk(node, path));
  }
  nodes.forEach((node) => walk(node, []));
  return results;
}
```

in which case the result array contains arrays of nodes, where the last one is the matching node.

Comment: Amazing answer bro .. you just nailed the problem :D that what I was asking from morning and people were just giving excuses to post my efforts.
Thanks a lot u gave very nice optimized way to do these stuffs :)

Comment: How I can delete the node from main parent element?

Comment: Done posted another question:
Find Value in JSON array and delete found node from parent node