# Find Value in JSON array and delete found node from parent node

Tags: javascript

```
var trees = [
  {
    name: "alex",
    lastname: "watson",
    city: "California",
    state: "Alameda",
    childrens: [
      { name: "shane watson", city: "Troy", state: "Alabama" },
      {
        name: "adam watson",
        city: "Palmer",
        state: "Alaska",
        childrens: [
          { name: "ana watson", city: "Avondale", state: "Arizona" },
          { name: "ama watson", city: "Douglas", state: "Arizona" }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "adam",
    lastname: "ronaldo",
    city: "Bradenton",
    state: "Florida",
    childrens: [
      { name: "austin ronaldo", city: "Alhambra", state: "California" },
      {
        name: "kira ronaldo",
        city: "Calexico",
        state: "California",
        childrens: [
          { name: "sam ronaldo", city: "Chico", state: "California" },
          {
            name: "godwin ronaldo",
            city: "Eureka",
            state: "California",
            childrens: [
              { name: "michael ronaldo", city: "Buffalo", state: "New York" }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

- Find out city in JSON array variable trees (eg. city = "Buffalo" or name = "Godwin ronaldo")
- delete found nodes from parent tree variable.

[this function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50908700/51685) gives matching nodes:

```
function findMatchingNodes(nodes, predicate) {
  const results = [];
  function walk(node) {
    if (predicate(node)) {
      results.push(node);
    }
    (node.childrens || []).forEach(walk);
  }
  nodes.forEach(walk);
  return results;
}
```

Function calling

```
const matches = findMatchingNode(
  trees,
  (n) => n.city === 'Buffalo' || n.name === 'godwin ronaldo'
);
```

I want to delete the matching node.

```
matches.forEach(node => {
  delete node;
});
```

output: SyntaxError: Deleting local variable in strict mode

https://jsfiddle.net/5sve3nxc/

Working fiddle to push trees child node. I want to delete node instead of pushing.

Comment: what do you mean by *"delete found nodes from parent tree variable."*? to remoce the object from the `childrens` array? btw, children is plural.

Comment: I have added fiddle @NinaScholz

Comment: do you want to delete the nodes and mutate the data?

Comment: yes, I want to delete nodes found using function "findMatchingNodes"  from "trees " variable. :)

Answer (score 0):

While you need to splice the array, if the predicate is `true`, you need to iterate from the end of the array, to maintain the index.

```js
function deleteFromArray(array, predicate) {
    var i = array.length;

    while (i--) {
        if (predicate(array[i])) {
            array.splice(i, 1);
            continue;
        }
        if (array[i].children) {
            deleteFromArray(array[i].children, predicate);
        }
    }
}

var tree = [{ name: "alex", lastname: "watson", city: "California", state: "Alameda", children: [{ name: "shane watson", city: "Troy", state: "Alabama" }, { name: "adam watson", city: "Palmer", state: "Alaska", children: [{ name: "ana watson", city: "Avondale", state: "Arizona" }, { name: "ama watson", city: "Douglas", state: "Arizona" }] }] }, { name: "adam", lastname: "ronaldo", city: "Bradenton", state: "Florida", children: [{ name: "austin ronaldo", city: "Alhambra", state: "California" }, { name: "kira ronaldo", city: "Calexico", state: "California", children: [{ name: "sam ronaldo", city: "Chico", state: "California" }, { name: "godwin ronaldo", city: "Eureka", state: "California", children: [{ name: "michael ronaldo", city: "Buffalo", state: "New York" }] }] }] }];

deleteFromArray(tree, ({ city, name }) => city === 'Buffalo' || name === 'godwin ronaldo');

console.log(tree);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Is there any other way, like to delete with matched nodes, The way I pushed to children node and it got updated to the parent node. I have already 2 node search calls running and again traversing the whole JSON will reduce the performance of the application, JSON Is dynamically created and it can be big